# What is the proper way to set options for the <Map> component in the React-Leaflet library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

The [React-Leaflet documentation](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet#map) specifies that certain *dynamic* properties can be set via props. However, there are [many other Leaflet properties/methods](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-class) that are customizable...the caveat being that in order to access them, you need to interact with the Leaflet instance directly ([mentioned here](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet#components) in the React-Leaflet docs).

I have not been able to find any examples of how to properly do this, but I did manage to get it to work:

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/jcarenza/yegL1j26/)

```
class SimpleExample extends React.Component {

  ...

  componentDidMount(){
    this.L.doubleClickZoom.disable();
    this.L.zoomControl.setPosition('topright');
  }

  render() {
    return <Map ref={(ref) => this.L = ref.getLeafletElement()} />
  }

}
```

Is this the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should do this way:

```
<Map center={position} zoom={this.state.zoom} zoomControl={false} doubleClickZoom={false}>
    <ZoomControl position='topright' />
    <TileLayer
      attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
      url='http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
    />
    <Marker position={position}>
      <Popup>
        <span>A pretty CSS3 popup. <br/> Easily customizable.</span>
      </Popup>
    </Marker>
</Map>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/n4emj929/

Same for other controls